# How can i assign division operator / to text word "divided" or "divides"

Tags: python-3.x

I m having a text , ***"Remainder 5 when 45 divided by 8"***

I just want to assign the division operator ***' / '*** programmatically  to the text "divide" and evaluate 45/ 8 and get the result(Remainder 5) .  Thus i verify that the text is correct.

I tried like this...

```
word= "45 divided by 8"
rep=word.replace('divided by','/')
print(rep)
```

But i am getting 45 / 8 , not 5 as Remainder

Comment: you could then `eval(rep)` it. It'll gives 5.625 in python3 (maybe you want the `//` and the `%` instead of `/`)

Comment: @Demi-Lune Is their any way in python, by which we can replace where ever text "Divide" is written by  /   and wherever  "Multiply" is written  by *

Comment: you just did it with `str.replace`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's about translating, a dictionary is a good idea:

```
translations = {
    'divided by': '//',
    'multiplied by' : '*',
    'times' : '*',
    'seven': '7',
}

def evaluate(sentence):
    for k, v in translations.items():
        sentence = sentence.replace(k, v)
    result = eval(sentence)
    return result

#examples
sentences = [
    "45 divided by 8",
    "45 multiplied by 8",
    "4 times 2 divided by seven",
    "4 times 2 times seven",
]

for s in sentences:
    print(s, 'evaluates to ', evaluate(s))

# displays:
# 45 divided by 8 evaluates to  5
# 45 multiplied by 8 evaluates to  360
# 4 times 2 divided by seven evaluates to  1
# 4 times 2 times seven evaluates to  56
```

Note that people often recommend `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`, see e.g. [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)